# Tools and libraries to use with J-Link OB and CoreSight

Tags: arm, debugging, swd, cortex-m4

I have a system with including a Beagle Bone Green board, a J-Link OB module and a Cortex-M4 microcontroller (see figure).

I would like to use the DWT and ITM features but don't quite understand how I can configure and access those register for tracing an application.

Is is possible to use the CSAL library for that or does it not work with J-Link? Or is there another c or python library so that I don't have to program the register accesses in my c files?

Thanks you for any hints

[image: setup]

Comment: I'd just try running OpenOCD on the BBG. Don't remember if it supports SWO at all, though.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think OpenOCD does support SWO since version 0.9.0: (" TPIU/ITM support (including SWO/SWV tracing), can be captured with external tools or STLink ")

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have decided to use the [pylink](https://pylink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library on the BBG to control the jlink OB module. Pylink offers all the DLL function for jlink.

To decode the DWT packets sent over the SWO pin I wrote my own parser in python. The parser is based on the [itmdump parser](https://github.com/arduino/OpenOCD/blob/master/contrib/itmdump.c) written for OpenOCD.